# Recycler view loads view items more than once and unnecessary white spaces

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Messages tree in database looks like as in the screenshot. [Here is the database message tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymVPd.png). I am trying to create a chat application using Firebase. I am getting un-necessary white spaces in my texts that I send sometimes . Also some texts repeats more than once and also change their position. I needhelp in solving this to fix it. The link to the image screenshots of white spaces is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/16J4XXC2b1ZEWRAXe30G15sSLK6qB0V7A/view?usp=drivesdk

The link to the screenshot of message change in position or item view of recycler view changes position is here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S81D_D-EELAMT03LSQEbr-D80FUQ-RCl/view?usp=drivesdk

My activity_chat.xml for the main chat page is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ChatActivity">


<include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
    android:id="@+id/chat_bar_layout"></include>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/message_list_recycler_view"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chat_bar_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/chat"
    android:layout_above="@+id/chat_message_linear_layout">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_message_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/chat_message_add_btn"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:contentDescription="add"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:id="@+id/chat_message_edit_text"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:hint="Enter message here"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/chat_message_send_btn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:contentDescription="send"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My single message layout for the recyler view item is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:src="@drawable/default_avatar"
    android:id="@+id/message_single_profile_image"/>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/message_layout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:id="@+id/chat_userName_single_text_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="@string/user_name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/_00_00"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/time_single_text_view"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chat_userName_single_text_view"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:id="@+id/message_single_text_view"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:layout_below="@+id/chat_userName_single_text_view" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/message_image"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_single_text_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My ChatActivity.java file is here:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String chat_user_id,chat_user_name,current_user_id;
private Toolbar mChatToolbar;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mUsersRef,mRootRef;
private TextView chatUserName,chatUserLastSeen;
private CircleImageView chatUserImage;
private EditText chatMessageEditText;
private ImageButton chatMessageAddBtn,chatMessageSendBtn;
private RecyclerView mMessageList;
private final List<Messages> messagesList = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayout;
private MessageAdapter mAdapter;
private boolean exist ;
private static final int TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD = 10;
private static final int GALLERY_PICK =1;
private StorageReference mImageStorage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    chat_user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
    chat_user_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("chatUserName");
    mChatToolbar = findViewById(R.id.chat_bar_layout);
    mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    setSupportActionBar(mChatToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth!=null)
    {
        current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View cutom_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_custom_bar,null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(cutom_view);

    chatUserName = findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_display_name);
    chatUserLastSeen = findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_last_seen);
    chatUserImage = findViewById(R.id.custom_bar_image);
    chatUserName.setText(chat_user_name);
    chatMessageEditText = findViewById(R.id.chat_message_edit_text);
    chatMessageAddBtn = findViewById(R.id.chat_message_add_btn);
    chatMessageSendBtn = findViewById(R.id.chat_message_send_btn);

    mAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messagesList);
    mMessageList = findViewById(R.id.message_list_recycler_view);
    mLinearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mMessageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mMessageList.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayout);
    mMessageList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mUsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    loadMessages();
    Toast.makeText(this, "messages loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mUsersRef.child(chat_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String thumbImage = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
            Picasso.with(ChatActivity.this).load(thumbImage).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar2).into(chatUserImage);
            String online = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();

            if (online.equals("true"))
            {
                chatUserLastSeen.setText("Online");
            }
            else
            {
                GetTimeAgo getTimeAgo = new GetTimeAgo();
                long last_seen = Long.parseLong(online);
                String last_seen_time = getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(last_seen,getApplicationContext());
                chatUserLastSeen.setText(last_seen_time);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    chatMessageSendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });


    chatMessageAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,"Select Image"),GALLERY_PICK);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        final String currentUserRef = "messages/" + current_user_id + "/" + chat_user_id;
        final String chatUserRef = "messages/" + chat_user_id + "/" + current_user_id;

        DatabaseReference messageUserRef = mRootRef.child("messages").child(current_user_id).child(chat_user_id).push();
        final String pushId = messageUserRef.getKey();

        StorageReference filePath = mImageStorage.child("message_images").child(pushId+".jpg");

        filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                    Map messageMap = new HashMap();
                    messageMap.put("message", downloadUrl);
                    messageMap.put("seen", false);
                    messageMap.put("type", "image");
                    messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    messageMap.put("from", current_user_id);

                    Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
                    messageUserMap.put(currentUserRef + "/" + pushId, messageMap);
                    messageUserMap.put(chatUserRef + "/" + pushId, messageMap);

                    chatMessageEditText.setText("");

                    mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                            if (databaseError != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                loadMessages();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });



    }
}

private void loadMessages() {
        //
        DatabaseReference messagesRef = mRootRef.child("messages").child(current_user_id).child(chat_user_id);
        messagesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Messages messages = dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                messagesList.add(messages);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                mMessageList.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size());

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
  //  }

}

private void sendMessage() {
    String message = chatMessageEditText.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        String currentUserRef = "messages/" + current_user_id + "/" + chat_user_id;
        String chatUserRef = "messages/" + chat_user_id + "/" + current_user_id;

        String currentUserMessageRef = "lastMessage/" + current_user_id + "/" + chat_user_id;
        String chatUserMessageRef = "lastMessage/" + chat_user_id + "/" + current_user_id;

        DatabaseReference messageUserRef = mRootRef.child("messages").child(current_user_id).child(chat_user_id).push();
        String pushId = messageUserRef.getKey();

        Map messageMap = new HashMap();
        messageMap.put("message", message);
        messageMap.put("seen", false);
        messageMap.put("type", "text");
        messageMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
        messageMap.put("from",current_user_id);

        Map messageUserMap = new HashMap();
        messageUserMap.put(currentUserRef + "/" + pushId,messageMap);
        messageUserMap.put(chatUserRef + "/" + pushId,messageMap);

        Map lastMessageMap = new HashMap();
        lastMessageMap.put("lastMessageKey",pushId);

        Map lastMessageUserMap = new HashMap();
        lastMessageUserMap.put(currentUserMessageRef ,lastMessageMap);
        lastMessageUserMap.put(chatUserMessageRef ,lastMessageMap);

        chatMessageEditText.setText("");

        mRootRef.updateChildren(messageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage().toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    loadMessages();
                }
            }
        });

        mRootRef.updateChildren(lastMessageUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        sendToStart();
    }
    else {
        mUsersRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).child("online").setValue("true");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser != null) {
        mUsersRef.child(currentUser.getUid()).child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
}

private void sendToStart() {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this,StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the height of messages change `match_parent` to `wrap_content` here:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:id="@+id/message_single_text_view"
```

To fix the order of messages add `orderByChild` to your database reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference messagesRef = mRootRef.child("messages")
   .child(current_user_id)
   .child(chat_user_id)
   .orderByChild("time");
```

Comment: I have added the database tree screenshot kindly check, and let me know how we can get time as there is another child(Firebase Instance id) between chat_user_id and time as you have mentioned. @Vadim Shved  and I have changed the match_parent part to wrap_content.